# CSS / JS not loading in custom Concrete5 template

Tags: php, templates, concrete5

I've got a custom theme running on the latest stable Concrete5 version.
It's all working great - but tonight I've come to create a variation of an existing template.

Inside the theme/themename/ folder I copied the PHP file for the template.
In the theme/themename/css folder I copied the CSS file used by the existing template.

In the CMS itself I created a new pageType with the alias to match both the php and css file's filename I'd created by copying the previous files.

The PHP / template file is loading fine when chosen as the template for a page, but it's now loading in the associated CSS file.

Cache cleared but to no avail.

Can anyone give me any clues what I'm missing?

Comment: This usually is because the css and/or js is hardcoded in the header. Check the html head (in the template) if the path to the css/js is correct.

Comment: Thanks - you're spot on, the previous developer had hardcoded the CSS links for some reason... if you want to post as an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1):

This usually is because the css and/or js is hardcoded in the header.

Check the html head (in the template) if the path to the css/js is correct.